# Monaco-Editor increase suggestion width using css or props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

Is there any way to increase the suggestion width in the monaco editor. I try to find around for an option but I am unable to find it anyway. Is there a css file or a classname that i can use to override the width of the suggestion?

Current way

[image]

Expected outcome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of @monaco-editor/react v4.4.5 there is no option for suggestions bar width.

But you can use CSS to increase it's width. Use these classes to change width of suggestions bar.

```
.monaco-editor .suggest-widget { width: 50rem; }
```