# React Monaco editor change suggestion width using parameters

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using the react-monaco-editor package and when I type html tags in the editor the suggestion bar is displayed outside of the container [monaco-editor bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBbPb.png). It can be reproduced in vs code, when screen is small.
Can I change the width of this suggestion bar?
I can solve it by overriding css as was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229955/monaco-editor-increase-suggestion-width-using-css-or-props), but is there a solution that can be used without this hack but as parameters.